# Set Firefox to Allow Cross-Domain Fonts

Tags: firefox, fonts, cross-domain, font-face

I have read that Firefox disables cross-domain fonts "by default." I use a website that stores its `@font-face` on a `cdn` subdomain and they have apparently not added the header information to their `.htaccess` file. I would like to enable cross-domain fonts in my Firefox configuration so at least I can view the website the way it's meant to be seen. I've done lots of research but can't find a way to enable it, but I have read that it's not supported "by default" which leads me to believe that it is an option. If it's not, does anyone know of an add-on that enables it, or another way I could enable cross-domain fonts?

Comment: Paraphrased duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541834/why-dont-web-fonts-in-firefox-work-on-a-different-domain

Comment: No it's not. Did you read my question?

Comment: I did. You keep saying "by default" as if it were an option.

Comment: I am asking if I can change the default for my own copy of my browser so it can correctly display fonts on a website I do not control. I know how to fix it for my own site, which is what the question you linked to answered.

Comment: Again, you're saying "the default" like it's an option. I linked that question as it explains the security protocol and what's needed to comply with it (server-side). That question also (in a way) asked if it could be worked around.