# Wordpress fonts different with Firefox

Tags: php, css, wordpress, firefox

I just migrated my website from a subdomain to the root by using this [link](http://www.webhostinghub.com/help/learn/wordpress/running-wordpress-from-a-subdomain-or-subdirectory).

It works in all browsers except firefox/IE, in firefox the fonts and icons are distorted.

The website is as [here](http://www.dts-solution.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had this problem before, Firefox and IE **do not allow any cross-domain font requests** (*which is correct by spec*) but Chrome/Webkit does.

This means Firefox & IE will not load your fonts because they are still on your test sub-domain but your site has moved.

All you need to do is **move your fonts to the main domain** and all will be sorted!

If you can't move your fonts or want to use serve your fonts from a CDN check out [David Walsh's post](http://davidwalsh.name/cdn-fonts)

Cheers
Sam.

Answer (score 1):

Because Firefox ignores fonts from a different domain. So if your site is http://blabla.bla and you want to use a font from http://fontfont.font Firefox ignores it.
There is a workaround: [Why don't web fonts in Firefox work on a different domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541834/why-dont-web-fonts-in-firefox-work-on-a-different-domain)